# How to parse @name of license from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have the following JSON that I need to pull `@name`

```
"@name": "Reuters TV iOS",
"license": [{
    "@name": "Apache License 2.0",
    "component": [{
        "name": "RMStore",
        "url": "http://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/"
    }, {
        "name": "mixpanel-iphone",
        "url": "http://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/"
    }, {
        "name": "facebook-ios-sdk",
        "url": "http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/"
    }],
    "licensetext": "text "
}, {
    "@name": "Apple MIT License",
    "component": {
        "name": "Apple iOS Developer Library",
        "url": ""
    },
    "licensetext": " text"
}, {
    "@name": "BSD 3-clause \"New\" or \"Revised\" License",
    "component": [{
        "name": "Reachability-DDG",
        "url": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Tweaks",
        "url": "http://github.com/facebook/Tweaks/"
    }, {
        "name": "NYXImagesKit",
        "url": "http://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit/"
    }, {
        "name": "pop",
        "url": "http://github.com/facebook/pop/"
    }, {
        "name": "JLRoutes",
        "url": "http://github.com/joeldev/JLRoutes/"
    }],
    "licensetext": "text "
}, {
    "@name": "Deusty BSD- License",
    "component": {
        "name": "CocoaLumberjack",
        "url": "http://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/"
    },
    "licensetext": " text"
}, {
    "@name": "MIT License",
    "component": [{
        "name": "SDWebImage",
        "url": "http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/"
    }, {
        "name": "SVProgressHUD",
        "url": "http://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD/"
    }, {
        "name": "TableViewCellWithAutoLayout",
        "url": ""
    }, {
        "name": "OHHTTPStubs",
        "url": "http://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/"
    }, {
        "name": "XCTestAsync",
        "url": "http://github.com/touchableideas/XCTestAsync/"
    }, {
        "name": "objection",
        "url": "http://github.com/atomicobject/objection/"
    }, {
        "name": "houston",
        "url": "http://github.com/nomad/houston/"
    }, {
        "name": "YLMoment",
        "url": "http://github.com/YannickL/YLMoment/"
    }, {
        "name": "ReactiveCocoa",
        "url": "http://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/"
    }, {
        "name": "cocos2d-iphone",
        "url": "http://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/"
    }, {
        "name": "Aspects",
        "url": "http://github.com/steipete/Aspects/"
    }, {
        "name": "TTTAttributedLabel",
        "url": "http://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/"
    }, {
        "name": "Mantle",
        "url": "http://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/"
    }, {
        "name": "Masonry",
        "url": "http://github.com/Masonry/Masonry/"
    }, {
        "name": "apple_push_certs",
        "url": "http://rubygems.org/gems/apple_push_certs"
    }, {
        "name": "HockeySDK-iOS",
        "url": "http://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS/"
    }],
    "licensetext": " text "
}, {
    "@name": "OpenSSL Combined License",
    "component": {
        "name": "OpenSSL",
        "url": "http://www.openssl.org/"
    },
    "licensetext": "text"
}, {
    "@name": "SIL Open Font License 1.1",
    "component": {
        "name": "Font-Awesome",
        "url": "http://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/"
    },
    "licensetext": "text"
}, {
    "@name": "zlib License",
    "component": [{
        "name": "iCarousel",
        "url": "http://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/"
    }, {
        "name": "FXKeychain",
        "url": "http://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain/"
    }, {
        "name": "FXForms",
        "url": "http://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms/"
    }],
    "licensetext": "text"
}],
"isProjectComplete": "true"
};
```

I am able to get `name`, `URL` and `license`, but not sure how to get `@name` to display at the top, for instance "Apache License 2.0".

Here's the current status: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/7Lzwsv40/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like this

```
console.log(lic['@name']);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lzwsv40/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, your problem is that you can't use special characters like @ in JS property names.

Just use brackets: `json['@name']`